# How can I navigate back to main webpage from current tab, and the current tab is pdf file which got generated when I click "generate pdf"

Tags: typescript, pdf, automated-tests, puppeteer, chromium

I am writing typescript code to simulate user actions on a given webpage, and it is currently able to login and click "generate pdf". As soon as pdf generated the user will be shown new tab with generated pdf. At this point I need to make my puppeteer script to move back to original tab (first webpage). Please see below screenshots. Also, after pdf got generated I have tried `page.goback()` function , and doesn't do the job I need. I might have been missing something in puppeteer documentation. Please point me to right direction.

[image]

**below is the new tab with pdf file**

[image]

Comment: In puppteer when a click opens a new tab it will not be pointed to the new tab it will still reside to the present tab itself, you can check this by adding page.close() this will close the original tab instead of pdf tab

Comment: @jaswanth I knew page.close() will close my main window (or page) which I don't want to. Just to reiterate, as soon as I click "generated PDF" I will see new tab with new pdf page, until this point everything is ok. But, I want my script to get focus or navigate to main webpage. Note, I don't mind if pdf tab is closed or open.

Comment: try this out not sure if it works
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagebringtofront

Comment: "await page.bringToFront()" this works.